# How to take a sample that has the same average spend as my base

Tags: sas

I have a table with Gender and Total_spend variables. The average spend for women is 500 and the average spend for men is 400. How can I take a sample of the male population so that the average spend for men is 500 as well? I was thinking of using stratified sampling and splitting the spend into bands but is there an easier way?

Comment: Consider giving a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: How many males and females are your dataset and how big a sample do you want to draw? Is it important that the average spend of the sample is exactly 500, or should it just be close to?

Comment: How is Spend distributed for each gender? Like normal distributions, and if so what is the standard deviation?

Answer (score 0):

A 100% sample of the original data, without replacements, would create the exact averages for male and female that you want. With such a small starting dataset, it's not obvious why you even need to sample at all.

Depending on the data, there may not be a perfect solution for any smaller sample. And if there is, finding one would likely be difficult.

"Sample" implies that there will be some degree of fuzziness around any computed metrics such as "average spend." Depending on where it came from, your original data collection may be a sample as well.

I'd suggest thinking through why you need the sample averages to [exactly] mirror the original data. In general, if you use enough data, they are going to be close. If you (or your audience) are concerned that you could get a skewed sample purely by bad luck, bootstrapping is your friend.

HTH